# I have written two C++ functions to insert a node in BST. One of the functions is working one is not

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference, function-definition

This code is not working:

```
void BST::insertNode(BST *root,int d){
      if(root==NULL) {
        root = new BST(d);
        cout<<"Node inserted successfully\n\n";
        return;
      }
      if(root->data>d) return insertNode(root->left,d);
      if(root->data<d) return insertNode(root->right,d);
      if(root->data==d){ cout<<"Node already Exists\n\n";return;}
    }
```

This code is working:

```
void BST::insertNode(BST *root,int d){
  if(root->data>d){
    if(root->left==NULL){
      root->left = new BST(d);
      return;
    }
    else return insertNode(root->left,d);
  }
  if(root->data<d){
    if(root->right==NULL){
      root->right = new BST(d);
      return;
    }
    else return insertNode(root->right,d);
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell why is it happening. Because I think the first code should work as well. Please share your insights on it.

Comment: Essential parts of your code are missing, especially the class definition of `BST`. Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Anyway: first code: if you call it with `root == 0`, you allocate memory with `root = new BST(d);`, but this will only modify the local variable `root` (parameters are local variables). Second code: if you call it with `root == 0` you get undefined behaviour, because you dereference a NULL pointer. So both look incorrect. But anyway without a [mcve] it's difficult to tell more.

Answer (score 0):

The both functions are incorrect.

For example the function that "works" does not check whether the passed pointer is equal to `nullptr`. So the first statement of the function

```
if(root->data>d){
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

The first function where such a test to equality to `nullptr` of the passed pointer is done does not work because it deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer used as an argument.  Changing the copy within the function does not influence on the original pointer.

That is the main difference is that the first function deals with copies of values of pointers and the second function deals with original objects by accessing them through pointers to them as in this statement

```
if(root->left==NULL){
  root->left = new BST(d);
```

In this statement the original pointer `left` is accessed through the pointer to it `root`.

The first function needs to accept the original pointer by reference.

That is it must be declared like

```
void BST::insertNode( BST * &root, int d ){
```

Also as the function is a member function of the class then it should be declared as static.

That is you can have two functions in the class. The first one will be a public non-static member function with one parameter

```
insertNode( int d );
```

and the second one is protected or private static recursive function with two parameters

```
static insertNode( BST * &root, int d );
```

The first function will call the second function passing also the data member of the class root.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems to work. Also I have added the first line in the second function to check for NULL root.

Comment: @MM1 If the problem is resolved then select the best answer to close the question.